# installing requirements-dev.txt from Qiskit raises an error with SQNomad

Tags: installation, pip, qiskit

I am trying to install the following requirements with pip:

```
coverage>=4.4.0
hypothesis>=4.24.3
ipywidgets>=7.3.0
jupyter
matplotlib>=2.1
pillow>=4.2.1
pycodestyle
pydot
astroid==2.5
pylint==2.7.1
stestr>=2.0.0
PyGithub
wheel
cython>=0.27.1
pylatexenc>=1.4
ddt>=1.2.0,!=1.4.0
seaborn>=0.9.0
reno>=3.2.0
Sphinx>=1.8.3,<3.1.0
qiskit-sphinx-theme>=1.6
sphinx-autodoc-typehints
jupyter-sphinx
sphinx-panels
pygments>=2.4
tweedledum==0.1b0
networkx>=2.2
scikit-learn>=0.20.0
scikit-quant;platform_system != 'Windows'
jax;platform_system != 'Windows'
jaxlib;platform_system != 'Windows'
```

At SQNomad I get the following error:

```
Downloading SQNomad-0.1.0.tar.gz (385 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 385 kB 5.6 MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/tmpta1cj_q6
         cwd: /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-install-pw0tuweh/SQNomad
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-j_5tehl8/SQNomad.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 77, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 299, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 306, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 541, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 577, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/pip-build-env-8qqwe_v9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 86, in finalize_options
        self.set_undefined_options('build',
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
        setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
      File "/Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: cpu_baseline
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/jim-felixlobsien/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/h4/1z5lkc1x4nb2s31y0f6y9r200000gn/T/tmpta1cj_q6 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anybody knows what is happening? I am trying to follow the constructions in the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjZdvNgYl3s&t=731s

The task is to contribute to qiskit!

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from a dependency in `scikit-quant`. The most direct way to fix this issue is installing the previous (0.7) version of `scikit-quant` instead of the current one `0.8`, as Qiskit seems compatible to it:

`pip install 'scikit-quant==0.7'`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with `SQNomad` 0.2.1; thanks to luciano for reporting.

But it's now also made an optional component of `scikit-quant`, to install with `scikit-quant[NOMAD]` if desired. It's quite a large C++ library and needs to be split up between its Python dependent and Python independent parts to prevent creating massive wheels, then the installation will be easier and it's optional status can be reverted.

All optimizers can in any case be installed and used independently (e.g. with `python -m pip install SQNomad` for NOMAD).